# Согласование WiFi с проводной сетью

Tags: сеть, wifi, роутер

Домашняя сеть состоит из нескольких устройств (компьютеры, принтер, камера и т.д.) и поддерживается роутером, который подсоединен к интернету через основного провайдера. Есть еще WiFi роутер, который подключен к другому провайдеру (телефонному) и выполняет роль резервного канала, на который я переключаюсь, когда у основного провайдера происходит сбой, локальная сеть на WiFi роутере не конфигурируется. Проблема заключается в том, что Интернет через WiFi включается, только если проводное соединение отключено, т.е., если отключена локальная сеть, что очень неудобно. Можно ли решить эту проблему без перенастройки проводного роутера?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно поменять дефолтный маршрут route ADD 0.0.0.0 MASK 0.0.0.0 10.0.0.1 где 10.0.0.1  - адрес WiFi роутера.В таком случае интернет будет работать через WiFi, а локальная сеть через провод.

А вообще лучше два маршрута с разными метриками, если один не доступен, то включится второй (как у вас), только не надо ничего переключать

```
route ADD 0.0.0.0 MASK 0.0.0.0 10.0.0.1 METRIC 3 это для проводного (основного)route ADD 0.0.0.0 MASK 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1 METRIC 4это когда проводной не работает
```

10.0.0.1 и 192.168.1.1 это адреса шлюзов в проводной и WiFi сети, соответственно.

Comment: Спасибо! Сейчас я уехал, через неделю, когда приеду, попробую это сделать. Хотелось бы пока прояснить несколько вопросов.  1) Правильно ли я понял, что настройку дефолтного соединения нужно сделать на всех компьютерах?   2) route - это команда ОС ? Написанный код нужно набрать в командной строке ОС? У меня Windows, на некоторых компьютерах 7, на некоторых XP.  3) У меня проводная локальная сеть настроена на адреса 192.168, в частности 192.168.1.1 - это адрес проводного модема в локальной сети. А адреса 10.0 никак и нигде не фигурируют. Как быть в этой ситуации?

Comment: Да, route - это команда ОС. В Виндоус работает в консоли (командная строка). На всех одинаково (ХР и 7-ка).  Эти адреса указаны "для примера". Вы можете использовать, например, сеть 192.168.1.0 - для проводной части, а 192.168.2.0 - для резервного канала.

Comment: Спасибо. У меня сейчас проводной роутер имеет адрес  192.168.1.1, устройства проводной сети от 192.168.1.2 до 192.168.1.7, а WiFi роутер 192.168.1.42 Все это хотелось бы оставить без изменения. Скажите, как в этом случае будут выглядеть команды?

Comment: справка: ввести в консоли:      route ?Т.е. в Вашем случае все-же лучше разделить по подсетям:  -#провод  route add 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1 metric 1  -#wi-fi  route add 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.2.1 metric 2  естественно в данном случае 192.168.2.1 - сетевой адрес wi-fi рутера  в принципе - все так, как и описал pyatak

Comment: К сожалению, я не имею доступа к WiFi роутеру (он подключен к телефонной оптоволоконной сети и администрируется телефонной компанией), соответственно, я не могу поменять сетевой адрес WiFi роутера. Я, конечно, могу связаться с ними и попросить поменять сетевой адрес, но хотелось бы обойтись без этого.